# Installing MSOLEDBSQL driver inside an msi installer

Tags: c#, windows-installer

I have an MSI installer for my product which needs the MSOLEDBSQL driver to run. I am trying to include the driver installation as part of the main installer and not as a pre-requisite (which is how it was being handled till now).

Following is the code I have written to install the driver within my main installer's code :

```
public static void InstallSQLDriver()
        {

            Logger.LogInfo("Installing the MSOLEDBSQL Driver");
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("msiexec.exe", $"/i msoledbsql.msi /quiet IAcceptMSOLEDBSQLLicenseTerms=YES  /qn ACCEPTEULA=1 /norestart ALLUSERS=1");
            startInfo.Verb = "runas";
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            try
            {
                Process proc = Process.Start(startInfo);
                proc.WaitForExit();
                if (proc.ExitCode == 0)
                {
                    Logger.LogInfo("MSOLEDBSQL Driver Installation successful");
                }
                else
                {
                    Logger.LogInfo("MSOLEDBSQL Driver Installation failed. Process ended with code : " + proc.ExitCode);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Logger.LogInfo("MSOLEDBSQL Driver Installation failed with error : " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

However, running this gets me an error with exit code 1618 in my log saying : `Another installation is already in progress. Complete that installation before proceeding with this install.`

I know that we can't run 2 MSIs concurrently, but are there any changes we can make to do what I am trying to do. Does anyone know how to avoid using a pre-requisite installation before I can start my main application's installer?

Comment: What did you use to create the MSI for your project?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MSI installer calling another MSI installer in silent mode using WiX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10052583/msi-installer-calling-another-msi-installer-in-silent-mode-using-wix)

Comment: It's not clear *why* you're trying to avoid using pre-requisites. They work, you say they've already been working for you.

Comment: It was developed using the WiX toolkit. I was able to run MSIs in sequence from the toolkit.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it (add a Custom Action) between `InstallValidate` and `InstallInitialize` in `InstallExecuteSequence` or after `InstallFinalize` (also in `InstallExecuteSequence`)